# C# フォームを連続で開閉を繰り返した結果、中途半端にフォームが残る

Tags: c#, winforms

お世話になります。

表題の内容では、ほとんど意味が解らないと思います。
Form1,A,B,C,D,E,Formlessという7つのフォームがあり、Form1はただ単にAを
ShowDialogで開くだけ、AはBとDを、BはCを、CはFormlessを、DはCとEを、
EとFormlessは末端の子供として、それぞれがShowDialogで開くという、
親子関係のプログラムです。

Form1以外のフォームに、フォームが開かれた後、自動で閉じるか子を開くかという
コードになっています。その流れをUFormという基本クラスで、Activatedとtimer_Tickを
使用して実装しています。Formlessまで達したときに、カウントを取り、
Aのフォームでそのカウントされた値を見て、一定値以上に達していれば処理を止めると
いった感じです。

さて、問題は無事にカウントが一定以上にたまった時です。Aのフォームでカウントを
チェックしている以上、Dialogで表示している全ての子のフォームが閉じないとAのカウント
チェックには到達しないと思うのですが、カウントに達した処理が発生した後も、
Bのフォームだけが開いたままになっています。これが何故なのか解りません。
AからEまで、構造は若干の違いがありますが、大きな変化はありません。
決まって毎回Bが開くというのが不可解です。

原因と対策をお教えいただきたいと思います。

下記に、全ソースを記述します(デザイン部分のDesigner.csは省略します)。
timerのintervalは1にしてあります。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

---

```
UForm　すべてのフォームで継承するクラス
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormTest2
{
    public partial class UForm : Form
    {

        public UForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.ClientSize = new Size(640,480);

        }

        protected virtual void action(string command)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(command);
        }
        public int ID
        {
            get; set;
        }


        private void UForm_HelpButtonClicked(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            this.help();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        public virtual void help()
        {

            MessageBox.Show("ヘルプが押されました。");
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = false;

            this.autoexec();
        }

        private void UForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Form1.auto)
            {
                this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void autoexec()
        {

        }

    }
}

Form1.cs(起動のメインフォーム。ここから始まります。)

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static bool auto = true;
        public static int count = 0;
        public static bool flg = true;

        private readonly A a = new A();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count = 0;
            a.ShowDialog(this);

            auto = false;

            MessageBox.Show(count + "回です。");
        }
    }
}

A.cs

using System;

namespace FormTest2
{
    public class A : UForm
    {
        private B b = new B();
        private D d = new D();

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnB;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnD;
        public A()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(580, 395);
        }


        protected override void autoexec()
        {
            int i = new Random().Next(2);

            this.action("" + i);
        }

        protected override void action(string value)
        {
            string st = value;

            if (st == "0")
            {
                b.ShowDialog(this);
            }
            else
            {
                d.ShowDialog(this);
            }

            if (Form1.count >= 100)
            {
                this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btnB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnD = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnB
            // 
            this.btnB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 22);
            this.btnB.Name = "btnB";
            this.btnB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 55);
            this.btnB.TabIndex = 7;
            this.btnB.Text = "B";
            this.btnB.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnD
            // 
            this.btnD.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 83);
            this.btnD.Name = "btnD";
            this.btnD.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 55);
            this.btnD.TabIndex = 8;
            this.btnD.Text = "D";
            this.btnD.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // A
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 480);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnD);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnB);
            this.Name = "A";
            this.Text = "A";
            this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.btnExit, 0);
            this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.btnB, 0);
            this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.btnD, 0);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}

B.cs

using System;

namespace FormTest2
{
    public class B : UForm
    {
        private C f = new C();

        public B()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // B
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(424, 267);
            this.Name = "B";
            this.Text = "B";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        protected override void autoexec()
        {
            int i = new Random().Next(3);
            this.action("" +i);
        }

        protected override void action(string value)
        {
            string st = value;
            if (st == "0")
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                f.ShowDialog(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

C.cs

using System;

namespace FormTest2
{
    public class C : UForm
    {
        private Formless f = new Formless();
        public C()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // C
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(239, 226);
            this.Name = "C";
            this.Text = "C";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        protected override void autoexec()
        {
            int i = new Random().Next(4);
            this.action("" + i);
        }

        protected override void action(string value)
        {
            string st = value;
            if (st == "0")
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                f.ShowDialog(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

D.cs

using System;

namespace FormTest2
{
    public class D : UForm
    {
        private E e = new E();
        private C c = new C();

        public D()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // D
            // 
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(473, 408);
            this.Name = "D";
            this.Text = "D";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        protected override void autoexec()
        {
            int i = new Random().Next(3);
            this.action("" + i);
        }
        protected override void action(string value)
        {
            string st = value;

            if (st == "0")
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else if(st == "1")
            {
                e.ShowDialog(this);
            }
            else
            {
                c.ShowDialog(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

E.cs

namespace FormTest2
{
    public class E : UForm
    {
        public E()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // E
            // 
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Olive;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(823, 164);
            this.Name = "E";
            this.Text = "E";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        protected override void autoexec()
        {
            this.action("");

            this.btnExit.PerformClick();
            this.Close();
        }

        protected override void action(string value)
        { 
        }
    }
}

Formless.cs

namespace FormTest2
{
    public class Formless : UForm
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

        public Formless()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Formless
            // 
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "Formless";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        protected override void autoexec()
        {
            this.action("");
        }

        protected override void action(string value)
        { 
            Form1.count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: まずはちゃんとファイルごとにコードブロックで整形しましょう。ソースコードの部分を範囲選択して、エディタ上部の`{}`ボタンを押すことでインデントされ、コードブロックが適用されます。

Comment: すみません、まだそういった機能になれていませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フォームAとBだけにして、`UForm.timer1_Tick` と `UForm.OnClosed` で記録を取ると・・・

```
A tick
B tick
B closed
A closed
A tick
B closed
A closed
```

何故かAがクローズされた後にAのTickが呼ばれ、Bの表示とAのクローズが行われていますね。

流れとしてはこうです。

1. （カウントが一定数を超えた状態で）BまたはDが閉じられる
2. **ここでAがアクティブになったことでUForm_Activatedが呼ばれる**。
   この時点ではまだautoはtrueなのでタイマーが再開される。
3. Aから呼び出したShowDialogが完了し、autoをfalseにし、Aを閉じる
4. 上で再開されたタイマーが `MessageBox.Show()` と前後して処理され、BまたはDが表示される

ということのようでした。

手っ取り早い対策としては、ShowDialogが完了した時点でautoをfalseにするだけでなく、タイマーを手動で停止するとよいのではないでしょうか。

参考までに、冒頭の記録を取った際のコードを載せておきます。

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}

public class UForm : Form
{
    public Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    public UForm()
    {
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        this.Activated += UForm_Activated;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;
        Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + " tick");
        this.autoexec();
    }

    private void UForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + " activated");
        if (Form1.auto)
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void autoexec()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + " closed");
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static bool auto = true;

    private readonly A a = new A();

    public Form1()
    {
        var button1 = new Button();
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new A().ShowDialog(this);
        auto = false;

        MessageBox.Show("おわり");
    }
}

public class A : UForm
{
    protected override void autoexec()
    {
        new B().ShowDialog(this);
        this.Close();
    }
}

public class B : UForm
{
    protected override void autoexec()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
てっきり閉じないと思っていたのが、実は閉じてもまたすぐに
開いていた問うことだったみたいですね。
私も少し浅はかでした。
以前のこともあり、フォームの高速の表示、非表示には
不安があったのですが、何とかなりそうです。
おかげさまで解決できました。ありがとうございました。